# How can I do to export shapefile with symbology.svg COLORED to DXF format?

Tags: shapefile, symbology, color, svg, dxf

I created a shapefile categorized by characteristics, and I assigned to each element a SYMBOL.svg COLORED with Design Effects.

I want to export the shape with the characteristics of the colored symbols.svg that I created and I do:

Project> Export> Export project to DXF ...

but when I open the file.dxf with AutoCAD, it exports only the symbols in black not with the assigned colours.

Do you know how I can do to keep the colours of the Symbology.svg to the shape during the export?

Comment: shapefiles don't store symbology in side them, it is usually stored in a side format like QML (QGIS specfic) or SLD.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option called Symbology export when you choose "Save as the layer as..". Look at the picture.

[image: Picture]