# Export DXF to QGIS and change symbol layers on QGIS

Tags: dxf

How do I change symbol color on export DXF to QGIS? I already exported DXF to QGIS 3.28.6 and need to change symbol color.

Comment: see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/387861/276